# How do you show $(ac)^2+(bd)^2+(bc)^2+(ad)^2=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Show $(ac)^2+(bd)^2+(bc)^2+(ad)^2=1$ if $a^2+b^2=1$ and $c^2+d^2=1$.

I was thinking about solving for variables and plugging in, but that seems like too much work. Is there a simple trick or realization that will help me prove this more quickly?

Comment: And you can do better: If $a^2+b^2=1$ and $c^2+d^2=1$ then $(ac-bd)^2+(bc+ad)^2=1$ and $(ac+bd)^2+(bc-ad)^2=1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: what happens if you multiply $a^2+b^2$ by $c^2+d^2$?

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& (a^2×c^2)+(b^2×d^2)+(b^2×c^2)+(a^2×d^2) \\
= {} & (a^2×c^2)+(b^2×c^2)+(b^2×d^2)+(a^2×d^2) \\
= {} & c^2(a^2+b^2) + d^2(a^2+b^2) \\
= {} & (a^2+b^2) (c^2+d^2) \\
= {} & 1\times1 \\
= {} & 1
\end{align}

Hope that makes more sense!